# UITableViewCellEditingStyle both Insert and Delete at the same time

Tags: iphone, uitableview, coding-style, edit

the book I'm studying to program for iPhone says I can have a mixture of both UITableViewCellEditingStyle-Insert/Delete at the same time. But I couldn't figure out how to do it.There's a UITableViewdataSource method return type of which is UITableViewCellEditingStyle.But how do I return both style simultanously if I can return just one thing-either insert or delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to update your tableview by both deleting and adding a new cell (and optionally animating that change).You need to nest your calls inside a beginUpdates block:

```
[tableView beginUpdates]
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths...
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths...
[tableView commitUpdates]
```

You need to make sure that your UITableViewDataSourceDelegate methods reflect that change when `commitUpdates:` gets called.

Comment: No, I mean can I have both - and + sign to the right of the tableviewcell text? The book said I could but did not explain how. The above code shows how to update a row.But I need a tableview where I can  both delete/insert upon wish.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewCellEditingStyle` is a enum, so I don't think it can insert and delete at the same time. Here is an answer that might help you:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
    }
    else
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
}
```